# How to speed up data manipulation in python

Tags: python

I have a large file of minute-level currency price data from 2001-2017. I want to create a simple nearest neighbor implementation to see if the % price change 5 minutes ago, 25 minutes ago, and 50 minutes ago has any explanatory power (I'm sure it won't but its just for learning). The way I'm creating the 'dif_X' lists is taking a ridiculously long time to set up though (like 5 hours). I'm extremely new to python and dont even know where to look to figure this out, but I know there is a way to make this run much faster in python. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def findNNDistances(df_):
    samp = df_[10]

    count = 0
    df_['dist'] = [None]*len(df_)
    while count < len(df_):
        print("Count: " + str(count))
        df_['dist'] = np.sqrt((samp['dif_5'] - df_['dif_5'][count])**2 + 
                                  (samp['dif_25'] - df_['dif_25'][count])**2 + 
                                  (samp['dif_50'] - df_['dif_50'][count])**2)

df = pd.read_csv("Downloads/AUDUSD/AUDUSD.txt") # this is a csv

df['dif_5'] = [None]*len(df)
df['dif_25'] = [None]*len(df)
df['dif_50'] = [None]*len(df)
df['index'] = [None]*len(df)

count = 99
while count < len(df) - 1:
    print("countA: " + str(count))
    df['dif_5'][count] = (df['close'][count] - df['close'][count - 5])/df['close'][count-5]
    df['dif_25'][count] = (df['close'][count] - df['close'][count - 25])/df['close'][count-25]
    df['dif_50'][count] = (df['close'][count] - df['close'][count - 50])/df['close'][count-50] 
    df['index'][count] = count - 99
    count += 1

half_size = int(np.round(len(df)/2))
train = df[99:half_size] # not used yet
test = df[half_size + 1: len(df) - 1] # not used yet
df.apply(findNNDistances)
print(df['dist'].head(20))
```

How can I make this run faster?
I'd also appreciate general tips on making things like this run faster in python.
Thanks.

Comment: How big is your *large file*? And by `dif_x`, you actually mean the `df_x` items, no?

Comment: Yes, by dif_X i meant the different lists stored in the dataframe with keys that start with dif_ (dif_5, dif_25). And it has somewhere around 7 billion closing price data points. I'm expecting it to take a while, but I'm sure there must be a faster way to do what I've done above. Right now it takes about 1/2 a second for each print statement to show up in the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give tip's for you, what can work~
Anything written in Python will be slow compared to code written in a fast language like C or C++.

But interestingly, commands that other people have written that are available in Python are actually usually written in faster (“compiled”) languages, like C++.

When your computer is manipulating data (defining variables, running regressions, etc), what its actually doing is grabbing a little bit of data from storage, moving it to the processor, doing math with it, and then putting it back in storage.

To simplify somewhat, we can think of your computer as having two forms of storage – RAM (sometimes called main memory), and your harddrive. But these two forms of memory are very, very different. Your computer can grab data from RAM 100,000 times faster it can grab data on the harddrive. Because of this, your computer is much happier (and performs faster) when it’s able to keep all the data you’re working with in RAM. Indeed, if you’re moving data back and forth to your harddrive, it’s almost certainly the biggest bottleneck – doing actual computations is almost instantaneous compared to moving data back and forth to your harddrive on modern computers.

You can learn more about how to know if your computer is wasting time going back and forth to the harddrive [here.](http://www.tadawiki.org/index.php?title=Ta-Da!#How_do_I_know_if_my_data_is_fitting_into_RAM)

Are you tried to use numba\with pandas for it? I know know about your targets, but you should watch [it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYIPEDnp5C4) and check it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#using-numba)

To be honest i am far away from Big Data processing, just CV and ML\DP, but sometimes using such instrument's.

You can try to google about Cython (makes free Python from spending time of checking type of each variable) and Parallelizetion. I don't know last 2 ways, Data scientific using it, when need to speed up code.

Sorry for a lot of text, that's what i read about it and know~ Wish find good day for you~